# Mapping Joda Datetime

Tags: postgresql, jodatime, slick, slick-2.0

I have a table with this particular date column in PostgreSQL, I need to retrieve the all record based on one specific Id using Slick 2.0, I'm using Joda to manage the dates

```
MyTable 
(
    IdTable Int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(64),
    Created_Date timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now()
)
```

Then I try to map it in Slick in this way:

val Created_Date: Column[Option[DateTime]] = columnOption[DateTime]

As soon as I add the Created_Date column in my table, the method to retrieve the records fails. What's the right way to map a datetime with time zone in Slick using Joda? Any recomendation?

Answer (score 1):

To use a db type with a scala type, you need define a type mapper, which was used to convert between db raw data and scala object.

You can define yours by using slick `MappedColumnType`, since timestamp was already built-in supported by slick. 
Here's the [guide content](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.3/userdefined.html#scalar-types) for slick 2.0.3

But you can also employ other existing libraries, like: [slick-pg](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg), [slick-joda-mapper](https://github.com/tototoshi/slick-joda-mapper).

Answer (score 0):

I've been successful retrieving **timestamp with time zone** columns in Slick 2.x using:

```
def timestamp = column[Timestamp]("timestamp", O.Default(null))
```